# Web-Scraping looping multible dynamic Pages using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, dynamic, beautifulsoup

I want to web scrape predefined links. 
I want to scrape hiking tours from https://www.outdooractive.com/de/, in a specific area so i defined the area by 20 links. So far so good. I get the data for one link but when i try to loop it through the List of Pages it just goes through one Link. I hope its just my incompetence in logical thinking. If somebody could help me i would be very happy.

Here is my code. With just three links not all of them.

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import codecs


webliste = []
webliste.append('https://www.outdooractive.com/de/touren/#cat=Wanderung&view=listMap&wt=Nationalpark%20Bayerischer%20Wald%20(94258%20Frauenau%20Germany)&zc=14,13.54301,48.94731')
webliste.append("https://www.outdooractive.com/de/touren/#cat=Wanderung&view=listMap&wt=Nationalpark%20Bayerischer%20Wald%20(94258%20Frauenau%20Germany)&zc=14,13.5443,48.88763")
webliste.append("https://www.outdooractive.com/de/touren/#cat=Wanderung&view=listMap&wt=Nationalpark%20Bayerischer%20Wald%20(94258%20Frauenau%20Germany)&zc=14,13.4589,48.93163")


for Page in webliste:

        class Page(QWebEnginePage):
            def __init__(self, url):
                self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
                QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
                self.html = ''
                self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
                self.load(QUrl(url))
                self.app.exec_()

            def _on_load_finished(self):
                self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
                print('Load finished')

            def Callable(self, html_str):
                self.html = html_str
                self.app.quit()



page = Page(webliste[0+1])   

filename = "WandertourenLinks.csv"
f = codecs.open(filename, "w","utf-8")


headers ="Tour Name" + ";" + "Länge" + ";" + "Zeit" + ";"  + "Aufstieg" + ";" + "Abstieg" + ";" + "Link zur Tour"+ ";"  + "Anbieter\n"

f.write(headers)



def main():

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')

    containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"oax_dp_snippet"})

    print ("Anzahl der gefundenen touren", len(containers))
#loop

    for container in containers:

        tour_container = container.findAll("span",{"dir":"auto"})
        cont = tour_container[0].text
        print("Name der Tour: ", cont)
        tour_name = cont

        tour_data = container.findAll("div",{"class":"oax_tour_data oax_fl"})
        leange = tour_data[0].text.strip()
        zeit = tour_data[1].text.strip()
        aufstieg = tour_data[2].text.strip()
        abstieg = tour_data[3].text.strip()

        print("Länge der Tour: ", leange)
        print("Länge der Tour: ", zeit)
        print("Länge der Tour: ", aufstieg)
        print("Länge der Tour: ", abstieg)

        link = container.a["href"]
        link_a = link
        print ("Link zur Tour: ", link)

        tour_anbieter = container.findAll("div",{"class":"oax_var_pos oax_var_pos_bottom oax_font_smaller oax_line_height_14 oax_ellipsis"})
        anbieter = tour_anbieter[0].text.strip()
        print("Tourenanbieter: ", anbieter)
        f.write(tour_name + ";" + leange + ";" + zeit + ";"  + aufstieg + ";" + abstieg + ";" + link+ ";"  + anbieter+ "\n")

    f.close()



if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: I'm afraid there are a few issues here. Firstly, the code you have pasted is not valid, the indentation is wrong so it's pretty hard to read. Second, you are defining a class called `Page` inside a loop, I don't know why but it does not make sense, you should define it outside the loop. Then you should probably loop through your list or URLs and create a new `Page` for each one.

Comment: As a general tip, when figuing out a problem like this write a much simpler piece of code, try to strip out the page parsing for example and just figure out why the loop does not work as you expect, once it works add back in the other code A simpler example s easier for people to look at on Stackoverflow too :-)

Comment: Final comment - Outdooractive has an API, you shouldn't need to scrape the HTML to get the data you want - see http://developers.outdooractive.com/API-Reference/Data-API.html

Comment: @ Steve Haigh wow that was very fast. Thank you very very much. I changed it the way it is in my skript now. It could be that the indentation is wrong ;) (I am new to python and web scraping as well). I will have a look at the API.  Perhaps this will be the better answer to my Problems.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve Haigh Thanks the second tip you gave me was the best. Know everything works. I know its not very sexy programmed but it works ;)

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import codecs


class Page(QWebEnginePage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()

webliste = []
webliste.append('https://www.outdooractive.com/de/touren/#cat=Wanderung&view=listMap&wt=Nationalpark%20Bayerischer%20Wald%20(94258%20Frauenau%20Germany)&zc=14,13.32663,49.07201')
webliste.append("https://www.outdooractive.com/de/touren/#cat=Wanderung&view=listMap&wt=Nationalpark%20Bayerischer%20Wald%20(94258%20Frauenau%20Germany)&zc=14,13.30002,49.0945")
webliste.append("https://www.outdooractive.com/de/touren/#cat=Wanderung&view=listMap&wt=Nationalpark%20Bayerischer%20Wald%20(94258%20Frauenau%20Germany)&zc=14,13.22097,49.11664")




filename = "WandertourenLinks.csv"
f = codecs.open(filename, "w","utf-8")


headers ="Tour Name" + ";" + "Länge" + ";" + "Zeit" + ";"  + "Aufstieg" + ";" + "Abstieg" + ";" + "Link zur Tour"+ ";"  + "Anbieter\n"

f.write(headers)

def main():

    for i in range(3):

        page = Page(webliste[i])
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
        containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"oax_dp_snippet"})
        print ("Anzahl der gefundenen touren", len(containers))

        for container in containers:
            tour_container = container.findAll("span",{"dir":"auto"})
            cont = tour_container[0].text
            print("Name der Tour: ", cont)
            tour_name = cont


            tour_data = container.findAll("div",{"class":"oax_tour_data oax_fl"})
            leange = tour_data[0].text.strip()
            zeit = tour_data[1].text.strip()
            aufstieg = tour_data[2].text.strip()
            abstieg = tour_data[3].text.strip()

            print("Länge der Tour: ", leange)       
            print("Länge der Tour: ", zeit)
            print("Länge der Tour: ", aufstieg)
            print("Länge der Tour: ", abstieg)

            link = container.a["href"]
            link_a = link
            print ("Link zur Tour: ", link)

            tour_anbieter = container.findAll("div",{"class":"oax_var_pos oax_var_pos_bottom oax_font_smaller oax_line_height_14 oax_ellipsis"})
            anbieter = tour_anbieter[0].text.strip()
            print("Tourenanbieter: ", anbieter)



            f.write(tour_name + ";" + leange + ";" + zeit + ";"  + aufstieg + ";" + abstieg + ";" + link+ ";"  + anbieter+ "\n")











    f.close()



if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```